# Is there a way to find in what position a user has earned a badge, apart from mass API calls?

Tags: support, badges, api

Is there a way that I can find in what position I have earned a specific badge? For example, how could I find out that I earned the 356th Outspoken badge on SO, apart from recording that fact when I earned it?

I have found this API method that could be useful: [badge-recipients-by-ids](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badge-recipients-by-ids). I could call it on the badge ID I'm looking for and search for the userid I'm looking for. However, there might have been potentially tens of thousands of the badge awarded, and that means I'll have to have over a hundred API calls to find this for *a single badge*.

So, how could I find out in what position I earned some badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wooo, let's go to the Data Explorer! [What is my rank for this badge?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/167413/what-is-my-rank-for-this-badge)

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) + 1 AS Rank
FROM Badges
WHERE Date < (
    SELECT Date
    FROM Badges
    WHERE UserId = ##UserId:int##
      AND Name = ##BadgeName:string##
  )
  AND Name = ##BadgeName##
```

- **UserId** - Your user ID on that site.
- **BadgeName** - The *name* of the badge, cased properly. For example, *"Synonymizer"*.

Basically, it just searches for the date *you* earned the badge, then determines how many users earned the badge *before* that date, and adds one to get your rank.

**Note:** This is technically a guess. It is possible for multiple users to receive a badge at the exact same time, but I figured it's not really important to account for that case. You're *all* technically the same rank in that scenario anyways.

**Note 2:** This also always returns 1 if you haven't actually earned the badge. If anyone wants to update it with a case, go for it. Didn't seem important to me.

Comment: Ok thanks! You could also use the `Id` field on the badges, which is probably more efficient.

Comment: Yeah, and it would remove the need to type everything properly. (I still can't work out how `Tag Editor` `!=` `Tag Editor`.)

Comment: @michaelb958 It doesn't represent the *badge* ID. You'd have to type out the badge name no matter what. The Id is a unique number assigned to each entry in the table. Basically, Doorknob suggests you find the Id for *your* entry and then just count the number of Id numbers less than that (meaning they would have occurred before yours).

Comment: I just cannot make this work with spaces...!

Comment: Turns out I only earned Tag Editor since the last DE sync. Strunk & White works fine.

Comment: Someone should totally fix the whole busted `UserId` thing. Slackers.

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out when you were awarded the badge. This is the magic bit - the API just doesn't tell you!

Next, call `/badges/{ids}/recipients` on the relevant badge ID with a filter that includes `.total` as well as the default fields, passing the date you just figured out **plus one second** as `todate`. (As seconds-since-Unix-epoch, mind.)

Now, take your `user_id`'s position in the result's `.items`, and subtract that from `.total`. You have now calculated the cardinal version of your position in the list. (This works because the API method is ordered. I hope.)

For an example, let's take my Tag Editor badge (id #73). It was awarded to me at (checks the badge page on Meta) `2014-02-09 10:05:56Z`. That's `1391940356` seconds since the epoch.

Now, supply that plus one to `/badges/73/recipients` with this filter I prepared earlier:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/badges/73/recipients?todate=1391940357&site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!Sri2Wn_IJpJ_-whPrq
```

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "user": {
        "user_id": 223030
      }
    },
    ...
  ],
  "total": 201
}
```

Now, there are zero people in the list ahead of me, so I was awardee number (201 - 0) = **201**.

This *should* work even when you're more than a page behind the leading edge, as the results are cut off *just after* your badge was awarded, with simultaneous awards solved by the subtraction.

**Warning:** Multi-award badges (e.g. Nice Question) may or may not work properly with this method. I'll look into it.